# How do I launch my app from Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that pulls a Java app, compiles the Java files in .class files, and then builds an uberjar out of the class files and all the dependencies. I then have this as the final build step:

```
/etc/init.d/vivian restart
```

The restart function calls "stop" and then "start":

```
WORK_DIR="/home/jenkins/vivian"
NAME="venus"
JAR="venus.jar"
USER="jenkins"
DAEMON="/usr/bin/java"
DAEMON_ARGS=" -cp /home/jenkins/vivian/venus.jar com.melonapp.venus.Main"

start () {
  if [ ! -f $WORK_DIR/venus.pid ]; then
      /usr/bin/java -cp /home/jenkins/vivian/venus.jar com.melonapp.venus.Main 
  fi
}

stop () {
    echo "Stopping venus..."
    /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --exec $DAEMON --pidfile $WORK_DIR/venus.pid
    rm $WORK_DIR/venus.pid
}
```

However, I seem to run into this problem:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

```
On Unix, you can use a wrapper like this to make the daemon behave. You can call your command like this:

daemonize -E BUILD_ID=dontKillMe /path/to/your/command

Note that this will set the BUILD_ID environment variable for the process being spawned to something other than the current BUILD_ID. Or you can start jenkins with -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true - see ProcessTreeKiller for details.
```

But "daemonize -E BUILD_ID=dontKillMe" merely gives me an error, whereas "-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true" seems to have no effect? I added it to this file:

```
/etc/default/jenkins
```

Where I added:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true "
```

Should this file have some effect?

How do I launch my app from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo on your /etc/default/jenkins file. A hyphen "-" is missing before `Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true`. It should be 
`-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true`.
Also, what is the error you have for `daemonize -E BUILD_ID=dontKillMe`?